# FIO: distribute io_size over time_based runtime

Tags: io, storage, benchmarking, volumes

I want to test a volume's ability to handle io request while im doing some operation on that volume.
for this purpose i want fio to send consecutive io requests for 3 minutes and i'll do those operations on the volume while fio sending request, such that requests will be sent **while** im doing those operation and also **after**

For this purpose i want to use the attribute [`time_based`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html?highlight=based_time#cmdoption-arg-time-based) `= 3 minutes` (that is: `run_time=180, time_based=true`), and finish those operations within 2 minutes so that the operation will be issued **while** fio sending io requests and also **after**.
However, the snag is that for some reasons that inherited in those operations this volume can't get io request for more than 3gb, so im using [`io_size`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html?highlight=io_size#cmdoption-arg-io-size) `= 3gb` , but as stated in time_based documentation:

> If set, fio will run for the duration of the [runtime](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html?highlight=based_time#cmdoption-arg-runtime) specified even if the file(s) are completely read or written. **It will simply loop over the same workload as many times as the [runtime](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html?highlight=based_time#cmdoption-arg-runtime) allows**.

I can't allow it to loop and also can't allow it to finish after it sends 3gb cause i need thew operations to be taken in between.

For conclusion:
what Im actually looking for is a way to tell fio to send 3gb workload that evenly distributed over 3 minutes,
so that there will inbound io request in any time within 3 minutes and the total workload will not exceed 3gb.

Thanks

Comment: btw,  i see that there are more questions in StackOverFlow about fio, yet there's not a tag for it, I personally can't add this tag since i don't have enough reputation. if someone that has sufficient reputation read this, i suggest to add "fio" tag to help the community and to better classify issues related to this topic.